# The Earth-Moon Map Problem

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, coloring

The following is the Sulanke Earth-Moon Map.

[image: Sulanke Earth Moon Map]

A planet and moon have each been divided into eleven contiguous regions.  In both maps, the regions 1-3, 3-5, 5-2, 2-4, and 4-1 do not touch, while all other regions touch. For the [map coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem), all regions of the same number must have the same color and regions that touch on either map must have different colors. Regions 6 to 11 touch, or $K_6$, requiring six colors. The cycle 1-3-5-2-4 requires three more colors.  The Earth-Moon map thus needs nine colors.
I took a look at this [Earth-Moon problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EarthMoonProblem/) and found 790 solutions of type $K_6 + C_5$. I'd hoped to find different solution types, but only found similar cases.

Does any have a good method for [turning these 790 solutions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EarthMoonProblem/) into nice maps?  The program offers planar vertex graphs, but it would be better to give the dual graphs of these, optimized in some way. The Sulanke picture looks better than my vertex-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Automated planar layout algorithms often use a triangle as the outermost polygon, but Tutte's spring theorem states that *any* of the faces of a planar graph can be stretched to the outside. It might be aesthetically desirable to choose the face with the largest number of sides, rather than always choosing a triangle.

Another idea is somehow leveraging the circle packing theorem; I know that it has been used to design algorithms that generate layouts with good angular resolution.

This [blog post](https://four-color-theorem.org/2011/04/25/four-color-theorem-representations-of-maps/) shows examples of representations of planar cubic graphs, but does not discuss algorithms for generating them.

I also wonder if a simple algorithm exists that involves building a "shell layout" of a graph by first finding the center(s) of the minimum spanning tree, then accruing the layers.